# Spacing between table of contents, list of figures and list of tables is greater than for the normal headings

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, sectioning

I had the problem that the text was not exactly under the heading of the list of figures and tables (see the picture), so the following code snippet was added.
However, the list of figures and the list of tables were no longer displayed on a new page, but everything was displayed under each other.

If you now look at the distance between the header and the heading, you will see that it is larger than between a normal heading and the header.

How can I reduce the distance or make it so that the text is below the list of figures or tables?

[image]

I added

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% added
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
...
%and after \listoftables
\clearpage
```

Complete document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left={3.5cm}, right={2.5cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[%
backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
%,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
,sorting=none        % no sorting
,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
,block=none
,indexing=false
,citereset=none
,isbn=true
,url=true
,doi=true            % prints doi
,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    urlseen = {aufgerufen am}
}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}  % better than \bibliography



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[driverfallback=hypertex]{hyperref} 
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\ref{#1} \nameref{#1}}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = black, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = black, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = black %Colour of citations
}


\usepackage{listings}
\crefname{lstlisting}{Code}{Code} 
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Codeverzeichnis}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{codegray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{codegray}{\texttt{#1}}}

%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray_s}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{f5f5f5}

%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour}, commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray_s},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

%"mystyle" code listing set
\lstset{style=mystyle}


\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{%
    \leavevmode
    \raise.9ex\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\normalfont\tiny\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% added
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}



\begin{document}
    



\pagenumbering{roman} % Nummeriung Römisch





\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage

% 
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\clearpage






\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Nummeriung Arabisch



\newpage
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]


\chapter{Figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Pgfplot3d3}
\caption{Three dimensional graph.}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pgfplots3dexample.png}
\caption{Second 3D plot.}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\subsection{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 \hline
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{First table.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Scattered}
\caption{Scatter plot.}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country Name    or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
 \hline
 Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
 Aland Islands & AX & ALA \\
 Albania    &AL & ALB \\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
 American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
 Andorra & AD & AND \\
 Angola & AO & AGO \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Dummy table.}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | } 
  \hline
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
  cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Third table.}
\label{tab:table3}
\end{table}

Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit
mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.
Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your image after changing to `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` and removing the .bib line, it compiles perfectly in line on mine. Please in the future [provide a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245306), I turned your code from 282 lines into a 47 line example that still cannot reproduce your error, you are including packages, macros, `fancyhdr` that are not relevant to your issue. Could you please rerun your code again after deleting your `.aux` and other files as it is not reproducible on my system.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer, hence the community wiki, but to demonstrate what your code can be reduced to so you can get an idea of what is helpful to people who want to help you out. Your code can reduce down from 282 lines to 41 lines:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}           %---- Hyperref should always come last except for glossaries, cleverref etc.

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\clearpage

\chapter{Figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{figure 2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{figure 2}
\end{figure}

\section{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{First table.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{First table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is producing this output:

[image]

[image]

When I run your original code after changing `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib` to `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` (**note**: we do not have access to your .bib file so please use the `biblatex-examples.bib` or the `filecontents` method) and changing the graphics you use to `demo` with the `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` option (i.e. `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}`) this is what I am getting:

[image]

[image]

Can you please delete any generated files like `.aux`, `.lof`, `.lot` and try and compile your document again. People here enjoy helping and I try to too with my limited knowledge, but your error cannot be reproduced and your code is too long. Hope this helps, edit your question or add comments if the error persists after deleting any relevant generated files.

Comment: Thank you! But if I am using `\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}` and `\clearpage` the problem is that  the size to the header is larger than for the normal headings. So the distance is larger than with the normal headings, but it should be the same size.

Comment: This only occurs with the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables.